# Overlapping elements in scroll view

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview

Trying to make scrollView with elements created in code but i got overlapping this elements on each other. Scrollview itself made in storyboard. Here is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
    }

    lazy var im: UIImageView = {
        let im = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 74, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 200))
        im.backgroundColor = .white
        return im
    }()

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 284, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        l.text = "crazy amount of text"
        l.sizeToFit()
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: l.frame.height + 280)
        return l
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(im)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(label)
    }
}
```

[image]

**White rectangle is imageView!**

How to prevent overlapping these elements?

Comment: which part overlapped ?

Comment: @KKRocks white rectangle is imageView. So imageView is overlapped by text which should go after it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution using Visual Formatting Language. Here I put fully working no-warning code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView! {
        didSet {
            scrollView.backgroundColor = .yellow
        }
    }

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel(frame: .zero)
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        l.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        l.text = "REALLY HUGE TEXT"
        l.sizeToFit()
        return l
    }()

    lazy var im: UIImageView = {
        let im = UIImageView(frame: .zero)
        im.backgroundColor = .white
        im.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return im
    }()


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.scrollView.addSubview(im)
        self.scrollView.addSubview(label)
    }

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()
        configureSizes()
    }

    fileprivate func configureSizes() {
        let metrics = ["elementWidth" : self.view.frame.size.width - 20, "imageHeight" : 220]

        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "V:|-10-[v1(imageHeight)]-10-[v2]-10-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: ["v1" : im, "v2" : label]))
        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[v1(elementWidth)]-10-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: ["v1" : im]))
        scrollView.addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:|-10-[v2(elementWidth)]-10-|", options: [], metrics: metrics, views: ["v2" : label]))
    }
}
```

Here you will see blank white rectangle on the top - imageView and after imageView you will find multiline label that stretches content size of scroll view if it is needed.

Hope somebody will find this helpful and save you hours :)

Answer (score 0):

You can change the code of lazy variable **im** to

```
lazy var im: UIImageView = {
        let im = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: self.label.frame.height, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: 200))
        im.backgroundColor = .white
        return im
}()
```

For image to be on top you can add **l.frame.y = self.im.frame.height** after **l.sizeToFit()**

```
lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let l = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: self.view.frame.size.width - 20, height: CGFloat.greatestFiniteMagnitude))
        l.numberOfLines = 0
        l.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping
        l.text = "Big Text"
        l.sizeToFit()
        l.frame.y = self.im.frame.height
        self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSize(width: self.view.frame.width, height: l.frame.height + 280)
        return l
    }()
```

This will give you the desired result.
Hope it helps!

Comment: I want to be text under imageView, but for some reason text has no effect if I change y value

Comment: Edited the answer. For image to be on Bottom you can change im(imageView) and for image to be on top you can change the code for l(label).

Comment: l.frame.y is error. If I remake new frame I have some buggy interface without any text

Comment: You want to add multiple imageViews and labels to the scrollView. Am i right?